# How to get the Form post data on custom button click in magento2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, custom-button

I have created a custom button in UI component magento2 I want to have post data ( id ) on button click in controller

**Button in UI Component**

```
<item name="combinations" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Buttons\CombinationButton</item>
```

**Block**

```
class CombinationButton extends GenericButton implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
 
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Generate Combinations'),
            'on_click' => sprintf("location.href = '%s';", $this->getUrl()),
            'class' => 'action-secondary',
            'data_attribute' => [
                'mage-init' => [
                    'buttonAdapter' => [
                        'actions' => [
                            [
                                'targetName' => 'hairforadmin_formula_form.hairforadmin_formula_form',
                                'actionName' => 'generatecombinations',
                                'params' => [
                                    false
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'sort_order' => 100
        ];
    }
 
    /**
     * Get URL for back (reset) button
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/generatecombinations');
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
class GenerateCombinations extends Action

{

private $modelFactory;

public function __construct(Context $context, FormulaFactory $modelFactory)
{
    $this->modelFactory = $modelFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('formula_id');

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($id);
    exit;
}
}
```

Comment: any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

I did it using my custom form

Layout File **adminFrontname_controller_action**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <update handle="editor"/>
    <head>
        <css src="Vendor_Module::css/style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Block\Edit\Form" name="edit_contact2" template="Vendor_Module::block.phtml"/> 
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Controller**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Block;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class NewAction extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action {

    protected $resultPageFactory ;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct( $context );
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute() {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend( ( __( 'Manage CustomBlock' ) ) );
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

**Block**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Block\Edit;
use Vendor\Module\Model\CustomBlockFactory;
use Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Field;
use Magento\Store\Model\System\Store;

class Form extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic
{
    protected $_coreRegistry;
    protected $_gridFactory;
    protected $_systemStore;
    protected $_required_options;
    protected $_optionsFactory;
    protected $modelFactory;
    protected $_scopeConfig;
    private $_bannerRm;
    protected $_storeManager;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        CustomBlockFactory $modelFactory,
        Field $bannerRm,
        Store $systemStore,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->_systemStore = $systemStore;
        $this->modelFactory = $modelFactory;
        $this->_bannerRm = $bannerRm;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $context->getScopeConfig();
    }

    public function getBlock($blockId) {
        $model = $this->modelFactory->create()->load($blockId);
        if($model->getData()) {
            return $model->getData();
        }
        return [];
    }

    public function getFieldsByBlockId($blockId) {
        $fields = $this->_bannerRm->getFieldsByBlockId($blockId);
        return $fields;
    }
    public function getCardFields($blockId,$cardId) {
        $fields = $this->_bannerRm->getCardFields($blockId,$cardId);
        return $fields;
    }   

    public function getBaseImageUrl()
    {
        $mediaUrl = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
        $imageUrl = $mediaUrl.'fme/customblock';
        return $imageUrl;
    }

    public function getStoreOptions()
    {
        $stores = $this->_storeManager->getStores();
        $storeOptions = ['0' => 'All Store Views']; // Add the default option
        foreach ($stores as $store) {
            $storeOptions[$store->getId()] = $store->getName();
        }
        return $storeOptions;
    }

}
```

**My Template File**

```
<?php
$params  = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
$blockId = isset($params['block_id']) ? $params['block_id'] : '';
$baseMediaurl = $this->getBaseImageUrl();
$count = 0;
?>

<div class="page-main-actions">
   <div class="page-actions-placeholder"></div>
   <div class="page-actions" data-ui-id="page-actions-toolbar-content-header">
      <div class="page-actions-inner" data-title="New Customer">
         <div class="page-actions-buttons">
            <button id="back" title="Back" type="button" class="action- scalable back" ui-button-widget-hook-id="buttonIdiHMgFHjdv6">
            <span>Back</span>
            </button>
            <button id="save" title="Save Block" type="button" class="action- scalable save primary ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget" data-form-role="save" ui-button-widget-hook-id="buttonIdt6bFjhJr3W" data-ui-id="save-button" onClick="submitForm()">
            <span>Save Block</span>
            </button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<form  method="post" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('blocksadmin/block/save', ['_secure' => true]);?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="custom_form" id="custom_form">
   //form fields
</form>
<script>
function submitForm() {
    var form = document.getElementById('custom_form');
    var messagesContainer = document.getElementById('messages');

    if (form.checkValidity()) {
        form.submit();
    } else {
        var errorMessage = 'Please fill in all required fields.';
        messagesContainer.innerHTML = '<div class="messages"><div class="message message-error error"><div data-ui-id="messages-message-error">' + errorMessage + '</div></div></div>';
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        setTimeout(function() {
            messagesContainer.innerHTML = ''; 
        }, 4000);
    }
}
</script>
```